# What is Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection and Connection-specific DNS Suffix?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipconfig

```
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-xx-xx-xx-xx-F4
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 52-xx-xx-xx-xx-F3
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I've read from another post that this Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter is used to create wireless hotspot so does it mean that the Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection is used to create wireless hotspot? and if there is 2, does it mean that 2 devices can be connected when I switch on the hotspot on my laptop?

Besides, may I know what is the Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . and why is there no information on this line?

Thank You!

Comment: DNS suffixes are used to as a shortcut for DNS resolution. if my dns suffix is set as "example.com" and I ran `nslookup host1` it would look for the dns server carrying the zone "example.com" and look in it for records related to `host1.example.com`.

Comment: So does it mean that the Wifi is providing the suffixes in this case?

Comment: each network adapter has a primary dns suffix, and the ability to add more, in order. you can see this in the advanced IPv4 settings on the DNS tab. for a client it means that DNS requests exiting that interface and that are not fully qualified will have the suffix appended. I'm not actually clear on what happens when this nic is being used for a hotspot. its likely that it only affects local client configuration. for remote clients DHCP attributes like DNS server addresses and search domains configure the clients appropriately.